# Parsing a JSON file in Python

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am having a hard time parsing this JSON file. My goal is to put this into a MySQL table but I need help just getting a loop together for the individual parts. I can pull the file just fine.

My code so far:

```
include json
include requests

f = requests.get('https://example.com/file.txt')
print f.json()
```

My JSON file:

{"1617057":{"name":"test1","comment":"words words"},"1617056":{"name":"test2","comment":"more words"},"1617055":{"name":"rex","comment":"690512810, other words"}}

Comment: First, it's generally helpful if you show your exact code, `include` isn't a valid syntax in Python. Second, it's not clear what your question is, you've successfully parsed the JSON and now have a Python `dict`.

Comment: Neither is your so-called "JSON" valid. It look more like a ``repr()`` of a Python ``dict``

Comment: Does requests have support for getting JSON from a file?  What does `print f.status_code` tell you?

Comment: @Makoto it returns 200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can parse your JSON response.

```
import json
import requests

f = requests.get('https://example.com/file.txt')
resp=f.json()

keys=resp.keys()
for val in keys:
    print(resp[val])
```

**Your output would be**:

```
{'comment': 'words words', 'name': 'test1'}
{'comment': 'more words', 'name': 'test2'}
{'comment': '690512810, other words', 'name': 'rex'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code sample taken from a plpython function i have that fetches some JSON data and inserts it into a table within a postgres db.

```
import simplejson as json
import urllib3
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
req = http.request('GET', 'https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/######/markers.geojson')
reqJson = json.loads(req.data)

a = []
for i in reqJson['features']:
a.append( [ i['properties']['description'], i['properties']['title'], i['geometry']['coordinates'][0], i['geometry']['coordinates'][1], i['properties']['id'] ] )
```